# Limit a .NET Web API post to same origin

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using VS 2013 .NET Web API 2.

I know with .ajax calls you have to enable Cross Origin (CORS), however, how would I limit server side POST requests.

If I have an endpoint called `/api/images` that accepts posted images in the form of a Base64String, how do I make sure that someone can't submit a `POST` to that end point from anywhere other than the origin domain (example.com).

Right now I check the Request.Headers.Host and if that's not the origin domain I return a 403 Forbidden Response.

```
var origin = Request.Headers.Host;
if (origin != "example.com" 
   return ForbiddenResponse;
```

I imagine that is easy to fake. Is there another way to do this besides implemented a form of oAuth? Something simple like an API Key that needs to be passed back and forth (or is it possible that could be read via Fiddler)?

What I'm trying to solve is there is a flash object which sends an image to an api end point. I obviously don't want anyone else to be able to send an image to that end point.

Comment: What do you mean server side post requests? Like you have another machine that might trigger the post server side? I think typically that's handled by internal firewall rules

Comment: How would you setup a firewall rule to block Posts? Doesn't it all come from port 80 or 443?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but i don't think a firewall would work in this case. A firewall would only be able to block traffic from a given IP address(es).  If you don't know which IP's to filter you wouldn't be able to pinpoint the baddies.  I could be wrong, but you would also have to be in control of the firewall as well.

Comment: I suppose you could whitelist requests at the code level to IPs associated with your instances if you know them ahed of time.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can use CORS support for ASP.NET Web API 2

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

Article Excerpt ------

**Enable CORS**

Now let's enable CORS in the WebService app. First, add the CORS NuGet package. In Visual Studio, from the Tools menu, select Library Package Manager, then select Package Manager Console. In the Package Manager Console window, type the following command:

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`

This command installs the latest package and updates all dependencies, including the core Web API libraries. User the -Version flag to target a specific version. The CORS package requires Web API 2.0 or later.

Open the file App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs. Add the following code to the WebApiConfig.Register method.

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace WebService
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // New code
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Next, add the [EnableCors] attribute to the TestController class:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // Controller methods not shown...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without going into too much detail you could use some sort of public/private encryption key that gets POST'ed along with the image.

I just did a search and came across this article that might help you with the encryption on the Flash side. The article deals with databases but the info on encryption is in there:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS8AFC5E35-DC79-4082-9AD4-DE1A2B41DAAF.html#WS61068DCE-9499-4d40-82B8-B71CC35D832C

Once you have that squared away you could do the decryption on the API side.  They would just need to share a passkey of some sort.  on the .NET side refer to this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2009/03/17/authenticated-symmetric-encryption-in-net.aspx

Hopefully this helps a little bit.  Without the use of some sort of authentication method it will be quite difficult to protect your endpoint from spoofed posts.

Also notice that the flash encryption uses AES-CCM so you will have to do the decryption with this method on the .NET side.

Comment: And obviously this would have to be done over SSL otherwise someone could juse use Fiddler and see the "token" being passed to the end point right? This would be where I'd need to stop replay attacks using some sort of timestamp.

Comment: SSL is always a plus.  I think what you are reffering is a nonce. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce.